# npm executable path issues

Tags: node.js, npm, nodejitsu

So up until a few weeks ago npm was symlinking global installs into my /usr/local/bind dir - but this stopped and I am not sure how to get it to do so again.

I realized it because I could not update nodejitsu - the version never changed. I realized that while it was downloading it did not update the /usr/local/bin/jitsu that was there. Deleting the symlink and reinstalling jitsu did not fix it. Tried it with other packages as well.